# MySQL What charset/collation for Case insensitivity and Accent sensitivity?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, collation, utf-8, case-sensitive

I am looking for a charset/collation that would make it so when I do a

> SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username = "Warrior"

It only returns me the rows where username = "Warrior", "warrior" or "WARRIOR", and not "WÂRRÎOR" "Wârrîor" etc.

I found a partial solution, by changing the Charset to "utf8mb4" and the Collation to "utf8mb4_bin", now it seems accent sensitive, it differentiates "Wârrîor" from "Warrior", but it's also case sensitive, so "Warrior" is different than "WARRIOR" which is  not what I want.

I tried a different collations but I couldn't get one to do what exactly what I want. Any ideas ?

Below is a screenshot of the different Collations available to me in the "utf8mb4" Charset :

[image]

Comment: WHAT VERSION OF WHICH PRODUCT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that `_bin` means case and accent sensitive, in your case you should't use utf8mb4_bin.

You could use:

```
utf8mb4_0900_as_ci
```

`as` means accent
sensitive, and `ci` means case insensitive

Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
s1 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_ci
);

insert into t values
('WÂRRÎOR'),
('Warrior'),
('warrior'),
('WARRIOR'),
('Wârrîor');

SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE s1 = "Warrior";
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> s1
> Warrior
> warrior
> WARRIOR
> ```

Comment: I tried the following :  `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username = "Warrior" COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_ci`

But it says : Error Code: 1273. Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_as_ci'

Comment: I've been smashing my head onto all the different tutorials I could find on Google, and exactly none work to add the 'utf8mb4_0900_as_ci' Collation :(

Comment: I just realized I'm using MariaDB and that it's not exactly the same as MySQL and that MariaDB doesn't have those collations, fuck me.

Comment: There were a report about these missing collations : https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25291 but considering it's been over a year the issue was brought in, and no one seemed to acknowledge it, it's fair to consider it could take forever to be done..

So I don't know, I'll wait a few days to see if someone has a solution, if not I'll consider switching from MariaDB.

Comment: I found a solution.
Simply using : `f\`...WHERE BINARY LOWER(\`username\`) = '${Warrior.toLowerCase()}\'`\`

Not sure how I didn't see that earlier.
I'll mark your answer as Solution because it would apply to MySQL and I didn't specify MariaDB at first, but for people on MariaDB, thing above should work

Comment: Hello @lyeaf and Ergest. I realize that, from a practical perspective, a binary ( `_bin` ) collation _appears_ to be case and accent sensitive. However, people should be aware that, from a technical perspective, binary comparisons (and sorting) are very simplistic and cannot be "sensitive" to anything (ex: case, accent, etc). I posted a detailed explanation here: "[No, Binary Collations are not Case-Sensitive](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/07/13/no-binary-collations-are-not-case-sensitive/)".

Answer (score 1):

- _bin -- accent sensitive and case sensitive
- _as_ci (MySQL 8.0 only) -- accent sensitive and case insensitive
- _ci -- accent insensitive and case insensitive

This lets you see what will compare equal and what won't:

- MySQL through 5.7, plus MariaDB with utf8 or utf8mb4 -- http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html
- MySQL 8.0 -- utf8mb4 -- http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html

(Caveat:  Those were taken from specific versions; the available collations do change, but the collations don't change.)

Most, maybe not all, _ci and _ai_ci collations will treat "Wârrîor" = "Warrior"

All _ci or _ai_ci collations will treat "WARRIOR" = "Warrior"